# SQLite insert query does not work properly

Tags: sqlite

I have a database in **SQLite** with customers table below :
[image]

now when I execute below query on it :

```
insert into customers values('first','last','mobile','address','mail','sex','national','more')
```

it just insert `first` , `last` , `mobile` and `address` into (firstName, lastName , Mobile and address ) fields.

What is wrong with this query or table?

Comment: if you are talking about SQLite database, please remove the `mysql` tag. Can you reproduce the issue in the SQLite shell?

Comment: what do you mean reproduce?...i'm using SQLite Administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the insert with specified fields

```
insert into customers 
(firstName, lastName, mobile, address, mail, sex, nationalNumber, more) 
values
('first','last','mobile','address','mail','sex','national','more')
```